# Loading indicator in Angular 5 input component gets replicated

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I would like to display a loading indicator as my autocomplete input goes to get suggestions from a web service.

I have the following HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input type="text"
    placeholder="Enter a Suburb"
    matInput
    [formControl]="myControl"
    [matAutocomplete]="auto">

  <mat-autocomplete 
       autoActiveFirstOption 
       #auto="matAutocomplete" 
       [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of suburbList" [value]="item">
      {{ item.value }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
<i *ngIf="loading > 0" class="far fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>
```

With the following TypeScript behind it:

```
 loading = 0;
 myControl = new FormControl();
 suburbList: KeyValuePair<number, string>[] = [];

 constructor(private DataService: ListItemLookupService) {
    this.myControl.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(300)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(
         value =>
         {
           if (value === null || value.length < 3) { return []; }
           this.loading = 1;
           return this.DataService.loadSuburbList(value);
         })
    .subscribe(data => {this.suburbList = data; this.loading = 0; },
               error => {this.loading = 0;},
               () => {this.loading = 0;}
       );
  }
```

The desired result is to display and hide the FontAwesome spinner.

What actually happens is that if I type relatively quickly, multiple spinners are created and shown. I assume this is happening because there are actually multiple threads running to get the data from the web service (`this.DataService.loadSuburbList(value)`).

I don't want to make a singleton service here as there may be multiple autocomplete lookups on a single form. I have tried researching rxJs techniques for this and am assuming the answer is something like a C# delegate. I am not sure how to proceed from here.

*Note: I made this a counter rather than a bool so I could track how many times it was being called for debug purposes. I first assumed it must be something to do with switchMap not working as I had expected.

*Edit: On further testing, this appears to be a bug with the new FontAwesome package. If use a static "Loading..." string it works as expected.

Comment: Your understanding of switchMap is correct. Old request is cancelled with a new one. And I would expect counters like `this.loading++` and `this.loading--` behave the same way. If the problem is caused by fast animations, you can try to set up a subject for the loader and debounce it too, `loadingSubj = new Subject; loading$ = this.loadingSubj.asObservable().debounceTime(100)`. Instead of doing `this.loading = ...` it's `this.loadingSubj.next(...)`, and in view it's `*ngIf="loading$ | async"`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks @estus, I tried this suggestion but it still has the same issue. I disabled animations in fa, but it still creates multiple icons. I have posted an issue to their GIT and will update this response when I get a reply. 
For now I have added an animated SVG icon and that is working perfectly.